# float next sibling left of previous sibling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, css-float

I don't know how to or if this can be done with internet explorer 6.

I am trying to float the next sibling to the left of the previous sibling

This is what im doing and it displays correctly with chrome 6 , opera 9 and firefox 1+.

What the issue with IE6 is that the `previous (2)` is floated to the far right (where it would be best to be beside to `next (1)` that is on the left side of the page.

```
 .wrap{float:left;}
 .prev {float:right;}
 .next {float:left;}


 <div class="wrap">
 <div class="prev">previous (2)</div><div class="next">next (1)</div>
 </div>
```

If it can be done and you know how to do it i will give a bounty of 250 points

Comment: did u try !important in wrap class...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go: http://result.dabblet.com/gist/2489753

You can't use floats there, 'cause IE have a nasty bug, where it stretches the container that is floated to left (or is `inline-block`) if it contains the `float: right;`.

However, there is a rarely-used property `direction`, that can be used for such layouts: it's fully cross-browser and you can use it with `inline-block`s for the best effect.

So, for your case the code would be this:

```
.wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    direction: rtl;
    }
.prev,
.next {
    display: inline-block;
    direction: ltr;
    }
```

But the `display: inline-block` don't work for IE from the box, so you need to hack it by making it inline but with hasLayout, so add those to IE only in conditional comments:

```
.wrap,
.prev,
.next {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    }
```

That's it!

Step by step:

1. Make everything inline-blocks, so it would work in inline flow.
2. Reverse the flow on the wrapper.
3. Return the flow to the normal ltr mode in the children.
4. It's done :)

Comment: I would of loved to know how to to do this years ago. Thank you!

Comment: David: if its the correct answer, click the 'tick' so it turns green, otherwise the question shows up under the 'unanswered' category

Comment: This is amazing! (And don't forget to reverse everything for truly RTL languages!)

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if this trick works in IE6.

```
.wrap{float:left;}
.next {float:left;}
.prev {overflow:hidden}
```

I don't think you will need `.wrap{float:left;}`

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="next">next (1)</div>
    <div class="prev">previous (2)</div>
</div>
```

This way `.prev` gets the width left after `.left` is floated.

Demos:

With wrap floating: http://jsbin.com/exevis

Without wrap floating: http://jsbin.com/opehig

Comment: Thanks Andreas! AL for your reply, but the content needs to be as my example `next (1)` has to be after `previous (2)` in the document markup.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that the direction property is meant to indicate text direction for languages like Hebrew as opposed to laying out content.  While kizu's answer is very clever when dealing with the monstrosity of ie6, I recommend you wrap it in a conditional and be sure to document the hack even if you're the only developer on page.  All it takes are a couple of months and maybe a few martinis to boot, and this implementation will appear to be quite nonsensical.

Comment: This should be entered as a comment on kizu's answer, not as a separate answer.

Comment: Very true, but I don't have the option of replying directly to answers.  I'm guessing this is some kind of earned functionality.  Typically, someone has moved my comments to appropriate place.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize adding comments had to be earned. Well, hopefully you will achieve that privilege soon!